# Huawei Y330 bricked

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, boot-loop, unbricking, huawei

I have a problem with my y330 device, I rooted my phone and then I tried to install CWM but when I rebooted my phone, it started to reboot gain and again and I can`t enter the recovery.
What can I do? Thanks

Comment: That's called a "boot-loop". Please checkout our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for first aid. Though it looks a bit different, as you cannot even enter recovery…

Comment: I can´t enter into safe mode or recovery, so do you know how can I fix this problem? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No. When you can't enter either of them, I don't know. Can you remove the battery for a while? Sometimes that helps (but I don't know whether the Y330 has a removable battery).

Comment: It has a removable battery and I tried it too but the same happens. I don´t know what can I do because I tried to connect the device on my PC but my PC only recognize it with the name "Android" and I can´t modify nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[Download the firmware](http://www.huawei-file.com/index.php?dir=/Y_Series/Y330-U01) suitable for your country and device, [flash it with flashtools](http://androidxda.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool) (simply turn phone off and when you have flashtools ready, connect the USB cable to phone (better try first to let windows install proper driver)) search for vcomm driver if win fails.

Comment: Can you explain this in better detail please, for those that run into this same problem